# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError while integrating Epson JavaPOS for printing

Tags: javapos

I need help resolving this error.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jp_co_epson_upos_firm_FirmNativeAccess_1_14_0001 in java.library.path
```

I want to use EpsonJavaPOS for printing.

Following are the steps I've succeeded so far.

1. Tried to install JavaPOS in windows 10(64 bit), But was partially successful
   and hence copied the installation folder in windows 7 to windows 10.
2. I've configured the printer in setupPOS.exe application.
3. And as a next step I'm trying to run checkup health from checkuphealth.bat file
   But receiving the above mentioned exception.
4. If I try to use the `System.setProperty(JposPropertiesConst.JPOS_POPULATOR_FILE_PROP_NAME, "/path of jpos.xml");`
   as solution to the above mentioned exception, It's throwing null pointer exception.

Can anyone help on these issues?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Look as if the Java can't find a DLL it needs. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your process can't find the file "jp_co_epson_upos_firm_firmnativeaccess.dll"

One solution is to add the folder containing the file to the Windows PATH environment variable.

I found this file in my prior version of Java:
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\bin

It was not installed in my Java 8 jre when I reinstalled the ADK driver after adding Java 8 to my system.

I have added it as a library in my application and it resolved this issue.